# Set maximum width of rectangle in a diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw a diagram like the following:

[image: Desired Diagram]

My main problems are that I dont know how to set a maximum width for the rectangles, and I dont know how to replicate the "re-do" symbol around the \Delta t.

My code is:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, minimum height = 1cm]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Model}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [block] (load) {Load macro-particles};
    \node [block, below of=load] (step1) {Integration of equations of motion, moving particles};
    \node [below of=step1] (evol) {$\Delta t$};
    \node [block, right of=evol] (step2) {Weighting};
    \node [block, below of=evol] (step3) {Integration of field equations on grid};
    \node [block, left of=evol] (step4) {Weighting};
    \path[line] (load) -- (step1);
    \draw (step1) |- (step2);
    \draw (step2) |- (step3);
    \draw (step3) |- (step4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

And my diagram looks like, which I guess would be fixed by the appropriate widths:

[image: My]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way. There is no `maximum width` but you can choose a `text width` to have an effective maximum width. I also switched to use `positioning` for node positioning, `arrows.meta` instead of `arrows`, got rid of the `\tikzstyle` command, and added the missing lines and arcs.

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending,positioning,shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Model}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[block/.style={rectangle, draw, minimum height = 1cm,
        text width=4.2cm,align=center},
        line/.style={draw, -Latex},node distance=2em]
    \node [block] (load) {Load macro-particles};
    \node [block, below=1em of load] (step1) {Integration of equations of motion, moving particles};
    \node [below=of step1] (evol) {$\Delta t$};
    \node [block, right=of evol] (step2) {Weighting};
    \node [block, below=of evol] (step3) {Integration of field equations on grid};
    \node [block, left=of evol] (step4) {Weighting};
    \path[line] (load) -- (step1);
    \draw (step1) -| (step2) |- (step3) -| (step4) |- (step1);
    \draw[thick,-{Stealth[bend]}] 
    (evol.center) ++ (45:1.5em) arc[start angle=45,end angle=-225,radius=1.5em];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]